# Converting a numeric value into Date value in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I have a DB2 table where NUM column is defined as INTEGER in DB2 and the query result is shown below,

[image]

NUM columns have numeric values which needs to be converted to date format. This numeric values are nothing but duration from 01.01.1850. Example : 01.01.1850 + 57677 days = 01.12.2007.

So Is it possible to convert or cast the numeric value into date fields in DB2 , so that the select query from the table can result as shown below after converting a numeric field into date field,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may use the scalar `ADD_DAYS` function:

```sql
SELECT EMP_ID, ADD_DAYS('1850-01-01', NUM) AS NUM
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all Db2 products & versions have the `ADD_DAYS` function.
The following expression works for all of them.
You may optionally add  `DAY` or  `DAYS` at the end.

```
DATE ('1850-01-01') + 57677
```